# How can I change the value of a variable when referring it from an array?

Tags: swift

I was wondering if it is possible to change a variable when referring it from an array, for example:

```
class Grades {
    static var student1 = 9
    static var allStudents = [student1]
}

Grades.student1  // is 9
Grades.allStudents // is [9]

for index in 0..<Grades.allStudents.count {
    Grades.allStudents[index] += 1
}

Grades.student1 // is 9
Grades.allStudents // is [10]
```

How can I change Grades.student1 using an array in order to be 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to create a Student class and add a property grade to it. This way you can pass it as a reference:

```
class Student {
    var grade: Int = 0
    init(_ grade: Int) {
        self.grade = grade
    }
}
```

---

```
class Grades {
    static var student1: Student = .init(9)
    static var allStudents = [student1]
}
```

---

```
Grades.student1.grade  // is 9
Grades.allStudents // is [{grade 9}]
```

---

```
for index in Grades.allStudents.indices {
    Grades.allStudents[index].grade += 1
}
```

---

```
Grades.student1.grade // is 10
Grades.allStudents // is [{grade 10}]
```